# Why am I getting wrong offsetX and offsetY in my event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom-events, react-typescript

I am trying to make a selection when a button is clicked.

I added a log function to place div elements in x,y coordinates.

As you can see in this image, when I stretch the selection area the coordinates are displayed normally:

[image]

But when I try to shrink the selection area, I get the wrong `offsetX` and `offsetY`.

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening and I hope to get a hint from you.

I've created an codesandbox, you can check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-shape-hp3ho?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1967

App.tsx from codesandbox:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import css from "./App.module.css";
import "./styles.css";

const log: Function = (x: number, y: number) => {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.position = "fixed";
  div.style.width = "3px";
  div.style.height = "3px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  div.style.borderRadius = "5px";
  div.style.zIndex = "4000000000000";
  div.style.left = `${x}px`;
  div.style.top = `${y}px`;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
};

export default function App() {
  const [mousedown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);

  const [offsetXStart, setOffsetXStart] = useState(0);
  const [offsetYStart, setOffsetYStart] = useState(0);

  const [offsetX, setOffsetX] = useState(0);
  const [offsetY, setOffsetY] = useState(0);

  const [selectionArea, setSelectionArea] = useState({
    width: "0",
    height: "0"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectionArea({
      width: `${offsetX - offsetXStart}px`,
      height: `${offsetY - offsetYStart}px`
    });
  }, [offsetX, offsetY]);

  const handler: any = (event: any) => {
    const nativeEvent: any = event.nativeEvent;

    if (offsetYStart === 0 && offsetXStart === 0) {
      setOffsetXStart(nativeEvent.offsetX);
      setOffsetYStart(nativeEvent.offsetY);
    }

    setOffsetX(nativeEvent.offsetX);
    setOffsetY(nativeEvent.offsetY);

    log(nativeEvent.offsetX, nativeEvent.offsetY);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={css.selection__tool}
      onMouseDown={() => {
        setMouseDown(true);
      }}
      onMouseUp={() => {
        setMouseDown(false);
      }}
      onMouseMove={(event) => {
        if (mousedown) handler(event);
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          width: selectionArea.width,
          height: selectionArea.height,
          backgroundColor: "#296CF2",
          top: `${offsetYStart}px`,
          left: `${offsetXStart}px`
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: not exactly sure what is going on where, however I notice on Safari, the blue box constantly flickers while moving the mouse. a larger box and a smaller box, with constant flickering between the two. The red dots appear on the bottom right corner of both boxes.

Comment: add selectionArea.width to your log statement. something funny is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild stab in the dark, but I notice the blue square is flickering between two sizes as you shrink it. And looking at the code, you are defining width and height two different ways, which could be out of sync potentially, thus causing the Dom to be working against itself?

```
width: `${offsetX - offsetXStart}px`,
```

and

```
width: selectionArea.width,
```

possibly eliminating one of these, and having a single piece of code that defines width & height might fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You put your "selectionArea" inside a div with a css class "selection__tool". Instead, place them on the same level:

```
return (
    <div>
        <div
            className={css.selection__tool}
            onMouseDown={() => {
                setMouseDown(true);
            }}
            onMouseUp={() => {
                setMouseDown(false);
            }}
            onMouseMove={(event) => {
                if (mousedown) handler(event);
            }}
        />
    
        <div
            style={{
                position: "fixed",
                width: selectionArea.width,
                height: selectionArea.height,
                backgroundColor: "#296CF2",
                top: `${offsetYStart}px`,
                left: `${offsetXStart}px`
            }}
        />
    </div>
);
```

or add `pointer-events: none;` to your "selectionArea".

```
return (
    <div
        className={css.selection__tool}
        onMouseDown={() => {
            setMouseDown(true);
        }}
        onMouseUp={() => {
            setMouseDown(false);
        }}
        onMouseMove={(event) => {
            if (mousedown) handler(event);
        }}
    >
        <div
            style={{
                position: "fixed",
                width: selectionArea.width,
                height: selectionArea.height,
                backgroundColor: "#296CF2",
                top: `${offsetYStart}px`,
                left: `${offsetXStart}px`,
                pointerEvents: 'none'
            }}
        />
    </div>
);
```

[CSS pointer-events Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp)